# red hat OSP10 deploy fails on node profile tag, even though it is configured

Tags: redhat, openstack

I am trying to deploy rhosp10, and when getting to "openstack overcloud deploy" phase, I get these errors:

```
Error: only 0 of 1 requested ironic nodes are tagged to profile control (for flavor control)
Recommendation: tag more nodes using ironic node-update <NODE ID> replace properties/capabilities=profile:control,boot_option:local
Error: only 0 of 5 requested ironic nodes are tagged to profile compute (for flavor compute)
Recommendation: tag more nodes using ironic node-update <NODE ID> replace properties/capabilities=profile:compute,boot_option:local
Not enough nodes - available: 0, requested: 6
Configuration has 3 errors, fix them before proceeding. Ignoring these errors is likely to lead to a failed deploy.
```

However, I configured 1 node to use control profile, and 5 to use compute profile. For example:

```
[stack@rhosp-1-director ~]$ openstack baremetal node show 4e153e0a-4c7b-4ee9-afb5-9036e263949b|grep prop
| properties             | {u'cpu_arch': u'x86_64', u'root_device': {u'serial': u'600508b1001c7b0731bc32edbb3a8369'}, u'cpus': u'48', u'capabilities': u'profile:control,boot_option:local', u'memory_mb': u'131072', u'local_gb': u'744'}         |


[stack@rhosp-1-director ~]$ openstack baremetal node show 4989038d-de10-4365-8051-44fd42fd0ec7|grep prop
| properties             | {u'cpu_arch': u'x86_64', u'root_device': {u'serial': u'600508b1001c73b9fa55f385cd1a4008'}, u'cpus': u'48', u'capabilities': u'profile:compute,boot_option:local', u'memory_mb': u'131072', u'local_gb': u'744'}         |
```

Another thing is that the following command yields no output:
    openstack overcloud profiles list

I am following their manual from https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-openstack-platform/10-beta/single/director-installation-and-usage/#sect-Registering_Nodes_for_the_Overcloud step by step, so don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

problem ended up being ironic auto cleaning. introspection never completed ok. not sure why, but disabling auto cleaning in ironic.conf right after undercloud install, followed by a reboot (for all ironic services to update this property), followed by the next steps, was successful (including introspection).